# How to response to the editor for a minor suggestion given by the reviewer via a formal letter?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, writing-style, editors

I submitted a paper and after about five months the editor sent an email: "I have decided that your manuscript can be accepted for publication after you have carried out the corrections as suggested by the reviewer(s)." The reviewer strongly recommends publishing the paper and besides of the nedded corrections of the paper given by him/her, he/she gave a minor suggestion:  "The authors may wish to consider posting some related questions to increase the interest to the readers." How to response to this suggestion and how to write a formal letter to the editor if we have no further ideas to add?  Does this lead to rejecting the manuscript? Thank you very much.

Comment: You really can't think of any ways to relate your paper to other outstanding questions? Is your research at such a dead end?

Comment: @Bryan Krause We are currently working on the topic and my professor says we will publish more results in the future. He thinks at the moment we may not add some outstanding questions.

Comment: My interpretation is that the reviewer is asking for hypotheses -- did you list them in the Introduction?  If so, then you can list further hypotheses in the Conclusion.  E.g., an interesting hypothesis is X, which will lead to the possibility of time travel.

Comment: @Prof. Santa Claus Thank you you are right. Or maybe the reviewer is asking for adding some questions  to the end of the paper to be persued by the readers?

Comment: @Fermat yes as long you can say 'As suggested by reviewer x, we have added blah in Section X' then it should be alright.  If not, the reviewer/editor can make him/herself clearer.

Comment: It's this a legitimate peer reviewed journal? Something about the language strikes me as slightly odd. Also, was there only one referee report? That seems unusual .

Comment: @user2705196 The editor might not be a native speaker. And having only one reviewer is not unusual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"**posting** some related questions" -- is that a typo? Should it be **posing**? Either way I'm not quite sure what it means.

*However*: It does not seem you are in danger of getting the paper rejected. You should write a polite response letter, list all of the changes suggested by the reviewer(s), respond to each one (e.g., "Done." or "We opted not to do this because..."), and thank the review team. If you do not follow the suggestion to "post some related questions," explain why not.

Congratulations. This seems like a good outcome for your paper.